# Node sso (sspi-expose) 401 when deployed to iis node

Tags: node.js, iis, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to deploy angular-node project to iis-node, and I'm using [node-expose-sspi](https://github.com/jlguenego/node-expose-sspi) for the windows authentication.
When running on my local machine, the sso works perfectly, exposing the user details,
but when I run it on my iis node server

```
const { sso } = require('./node_modules/node-expose-sspi');
app.use(sso.auth());
```

I get a login popup when I enter the client page.
choosing "cancel" returns 401 unauthorized "login aborted".

My anonymous authentication is set to disabled and Windows authentication is set to enabled.

Here's my web.config file (only the relevent part):

```
<handlers>
 <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iis"/>
</handlers>

<iisnode promotoeServerVars="LOGON_USER" nodeProcessCommandLine="c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of the node-expose-sspi module.

When a popup is coming during authentication, it means that the browser cannot send a Kerberos token, so the browser is using **NTLM**.

If the requested URL domain is not localhost, the browser must ask you the Windows account credentials you wish to use. This is why you see the popup windows with login/password. At this stage, if you click on the cancel button, the browser stops and answers 401 Unauthorized. **This is not a server behavior but a browser one.** There is nothing you can change about it.

If you want to use SSO without this popup, you need to use Kerberos. See the Kerberos documentation of the node-expose-sspi module.

https://github.com/jlguenego/node-expose-sspi/blob/master/doc/Kerberos.md

Comment: I'm very late to thank you, but Still, thanks for the advice and for your great library. We ended up using a workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In iis windows authentication set the authorization rule to allow authenticated users:

```
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

At the client Angular app, You need to set withCredentials to true on $http requests.

```
$http({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
        method: 'GET',
        withCredentials: true,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',    
            }
    })
```

https://github.com/Azure/iisnode/issues/95

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
This did not help tho, and I'm still getting 401.

Comment: @AmitayKaufman try to set the "Automatic Logon with current username and password" in the IE setting [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNtQi.png)

Comment: You mean Internet Explorer settings? I'm using chrome, also this setting is already set in my computer IE.

Comment: @AmitayKaufman yes internet explorer setting. and chrome also use ie setting so it may help you

Comment: This is not much help unfortunately. The problem is with the iisnode Negotiate and not with the client.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: No. I'm now using passport on the server and node expose on local...